# Implementing own blog engine with own PHP MVC framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks, blogs

I'm coding a website using own PHP MVC framework. I would like to implement a blogging engine that would allow to have rich text formatting capabilities, insert pictures, etc. I have however never done a blogging engine before so would appreciate some pointers / tips as to the best practices of doing it. Many thanks!

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel, right?  There are tons of blogging applications available.  Also, you should break your question into multiple pieces.  We can't help you with such a generalized question.

Comment: Reinventing the wheel indeed is useless, unless it is to learn the fundamental of wheel designing.

Comment: Brad, Clement, appreciate the comments. True, there is really no need to reinvent the wheel; however, I'm really interested in understanding the wheel-building fundamentals :-)

Brad, I guess the more specific question would be what are good blogging engines that would easily fit in my framework?

Answer (score 2):

What you're wanting has already been invented and has been refined/debugged well by an entire community.

Google TinyMCE, and that will help you on your path.

Comment: FinalForm, thanks for the tip! Checking it out now.